# Find the least multiple number- Python

Tags: python

If I want to find X and Y for X100Y such that X and Y are non zero and the smallest multiple of 100, what should be the code for this in python?

Comment: Could you show a little sample input output and code of yours

Comment: say input is 11004...If this is the least multiple then X=1, Y=4

Comment: I am not that good in maths can you be more specify `do you want first and last integer`

Comment: Actually can you tell me for X2004Y?...where if we substitute positive values for X and Y, and we could get the smallest multiple if 2004?

Comment: Yes I want the first and last integer..X and Y..both positive

Answer (score 0):

If X and Y are single digits, then no matter how long ABCDE is, XABCDEY divided by ABCDE can't be more than 1000 or less than 10, so just use brute force. Set x to 10, compute ABCDE * x, see if the middle digits are ABCDE, then increment x and repeat until you find one where the middle digits match or you reach 1000.

Comment: This is incorrect.  X=481, Y=8 is the minimal solution for 2004, 48120048 = 2004*24012.

Comment: Can you show your code and explain the logic please for x=481 and y=8

Comment: Oh, the phrasing of the question made me think that X and Y are single digits. Never mind.